# Resize a PictureBox in the middle

Tags: c#, timer, size, picturebox

I need your help today to resize a `PictureBox` in WinForms while keeping it in the middle.
What really happened is that the `PictureBox` became bigger and bigger to the Left and Down directions!

Here is my code:

```
public partial class Form1:Form
{
    private int x = 25;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        x++;
        pictureBox1.Size = new Size(x,x);
    }
}
```

**Note:**
I have tried changing the Anchor property - as I read similar articles - to everything (None, all directions...). But nothing changed!

Also, I have tried changing its location every time I change its size, but that was not a *smooth* move to look at!

Comment: Help? any idea could be useful... :-)

Comment: Did you try adding a `TableLayoutPanel`, with `Dock` set to `Fill`, columns 50%, Auto, 50%, and rows 50%, Auto, 50%, then placing the `PictureBox` in the middle cell, and setting `Dock` to `Fill`?

Comment: ok, and how to change the middle cell size?

Comment: By changing the `PictureBox` size.

Comment: it's not a smooth move! is there anyway to change cell size in one command?

Comment: @JoséPedroI can't change the picture box size since it's Docked inside the cell!!

Comment: It's docked inside a cell whose size is Auto, so it should arrange automatically.

Comment: @JoséPedro So, how to change the size cell Number [1,1]

Comment: The cell size is Auto, so it's adjusted automatically according to the content size. You just need to place the `PictureBox` in the middle cell and changing the `PictureBox` size should arrange the layout automatically.

Answer (score 1):

See if this progressive resizing is smooth enough.
The `PictureBox` will expand maintaining it's initial center position.
The `Timer` is set with an `.Interval = 100`. Each `Timer.Tick()`, the size of the `PictureBox` is increased by an amount (2 pixels, in this case).

The `PictureBox.Location` value is decreased by half of that amount.
Play with it until you find *speed* and size values you're comfortable with.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int PictureBoxResize = 2;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Interval = 100;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Left - (PictureBoxResize / 2), 
                                         pictureBox1.Top - (PictureBoxResize / 2));
        pictureBox1.Size = new Size(pictureBox1.Width + PictureBoxResize, 
                                    pictureBox1.Height + PictureBoxResize);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use code below after changing `pictureBox1`'s size

```
int righty = this.Width - (pictureBox1.Location.X + pictureBox1.Width);
int downy = this.Height - (pictureBox1.Location.Y + pictureBox1.Height);
pictureBox1.Top = (downy + pictureBox1.Top) / 2;
pictureBox1.Left = (righty + pictureBox1.Left) / 2;
```

i'm using it in my WinForm app and it's working .
it keeps the balance of four edges of `pictureBox1` between four edges of `form` and keeps `pictureBox1` in the middle .